# Mainting the state of array across the entire app using singleton pattern

Tags: javascript

```
function MySingletonClass(arg) {
  this.arr = [];    
  if ( arguments.callee._singletonInstance )
    return arguments.callee._singletonInstance;
  arguments.callee._singletonInstance = this;    
  this.Foo = function() {
      this.arr.push(arg);
    // ...
  }
}

var a = new MySingletonClass()
var b = MySingletonClass()
Print( a === b ); // prints: true
```

My requirement is i am pushing objects to an array on each load of window, but when i open the next window the state of the array is not visible.

```
var arr = [];
arr.push("something");
```

// It gets pushed.

When i open the new window, the array's length becomes zero again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this with JavaScript alone. JavaScript is *just* the language. It doesn't have any direct link to the app, the page or even the browser. JavaScript can be used (and is used) in many other situations, such as in server-side applications and as a plugin language for desktop apps.

Of course, when JavaScript is used in the browser, you do need a way to "communicate", as it were, with the content on page. For this you can use the [Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM) (DOM) API, which is implemented by every browser that supports JavaScript. To communicate with the browser itself you can use [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window) and other global object. These are sometimes referred to as the *Browser Object Model* (although it's not an official API).

Now that we know that; is there an API that allows us to maintain state between pages? Yes, there is. In fact, there are several:

- HTML5's [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage)
- [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie)

Take this example, using `localStorage`:

```js
// On page 1:
localStorage.setItem("message", "Hello World!");
```

```js
// On page 2:
var message = localStorage.getItem("message");
if (message !== null) {
    alert(message);
}
```

Easy, right? Unfortunately, localStorage only accepts key/value pairs. To save an array, you'll need to convert it into a string first. You could do this, for example, using JSON:

```js
// On both pages:
var arr = localStorage.getItem("arr");
if (arr === null) {
    arr = [];
} else {
    arr = JSON.parse(arr);
}

function saveArr() {
    localStorage.setItem("arr", JSON.stringify(arr));
}
```

```js
// On page 1:
console.log(arr); // []
arr.push("Hello");
arr.push("world!");
saveArr();
```

```js
// On page 2:
console.log(arr); // ["Hello", "world!"]
```

Keep in mind, though, that `localStorage` and `JSON` are both fairly new, so only modern browsers support them. Have a look at [emulating localStorage using cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage_compatibility) and at  [JSON2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Answer (score 1):

For data to persist across an application, there must be a database.  Javascript cannot accomplish this because it is client side only and mostly intended as a way to render user interfaces.